# using perforce with LSF is causing an error about a password

Tags: perforce, lsf

when I submit the following command to LSF it fails.

```
> bsub -I p4 client -o
Job <7966594> is submitted to default queue <normal>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on XXX>>
Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
```

how do I set the password for the LSF job?

Comment: found it - need to log in with : p4 login -a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to use : p4 login -a

that makes the login valid on all hosts